# Where are package key-bindings?

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed [ColorPicker](https://github.com/weslly/ColorPicker) and it overwrote my key-binding (`ctrl+shift+c`). I'd like to change the ColorPicker binding to something else, however I'm unable to locate the definition.

If looked in Preferences > Package Settings > ColorPicker, but it only has `Settings-Default` and `Settings-User` neither of which contain the key-binding. I've also checked the Default & User key-bindings, to no avail.

**How can I change the key-binding for ColorPicker?**

Edit: Adding image of files for [@OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The definition for key bindings in a Sublime package come from the file `Default (Platform).sublime-keymap`, where `Platform` is one of `Windows`, `Linux` or `OSX`. Not all packages provide a menu entry for editing key bindings, though.

You can use [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to open the file and see what the key binding is set to. You can modify the key directly in that file or copy it to your custom key bindings in your `User` package.

The latter is generally the better way to go because overriding a package file can cause problems when the package updates in the future; if it modifies a file that you have overridden, your override masks the package file which can potentially cause problems.

Sublime takes care to ensure that the `User` package is loaded last, so this is  good place to put settings that you want to make sure don't get hoisted out from under you by packages.

Comment: OK, so here's what I'm not getting about your solution: I already have `ctrl+shift+c` defined in my user key-bindings, so copying it there wouldn't overwrite it correct? I'm forced to change the default file, right?

Comment: Hmm. If there is a binding to that key in your User key bindings, that should be the one that's used; the plugin shouldn't be able to overwrite it with its own.  For key bindings it's generally pretty safe to change the default right in the package though.

Comment: I can't replicate your result; if I have a binding in my `Packages\User\Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` file that binds this key to e.g. toggle the side bar, when I install the plugin the key still toggles the sidebar and I have to manually create a binding to invoke color picker. Can you verify what file your ignored key binding is stored in?

Comment: I posted an image of the two files. They both have the same name, but live in different dirs. Was it perhaps a mistake of the devs to name this the same thing as the user keymap?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work; files with the same name but in different package (here one is ColorPicker and the other is User; there is a third one in the package named Default) are combined together into one file when they're loaded. The Default package is always first and the User package is alwas last, so the package should not have been able to clobber your custom keybinding in the User file.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, so why is this key-binding overwriting my key-binding? Maybe I'll write the devs an email...

Comment: I can't see how it can overwrite. Note however that the binding on the right (from your `User` package) has a selector context, so it is only active when you're editing a certain type of file or in a certain part of a file (which is unclear; the image cuts off the rest of the context). If that was the only key binding you had to that key, you might notice that where the key did nothing before, it now does the new thing. Your context should take priority otherwise, I think.